# How to use Equatable protocol on two objects of an unknown type?

Tags: swift

Say I have two variables, and I don't know what type they are (and it's not possible to know what type they are until runtime):

```
var a: Any
var b: Any
```

How can I test if they are equal, using the `Equatable` protocol? I can't just do `a == b` because that requires that both of the items are the same, `Equatable` type, and the compiler can't prove that because they could be different types (and one or both might not even be `Equatable`).

So, is it possible to tell the compiler to check if they both have the same type, and if that type conforms to `Equatable`, then to use the `==` operator on them and return the result, otherwise returning false?

If there is no way to do this, is there a good reason Swift prevents this, or is it a current limitation of Swift that could be fixed in the future?

Comment: How did you implement this? I have the same issue

Comment: In my specific situation, I did know that my two variables were of a specific custom protocol I had made, so I just added an `isEqualTo` method to that protocol, and then implemented for every object type. As part of each implementation, I manually make sure that the other object is of the correct type first, which lets me then use the standard `Equatable`'s `==` operator to compare them.

Comment: If you truly don't know any type information about your two variables, I suspect it'll be a lot more difficult!

Comment: Related section in Generics Manifesto: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#opening-existentials

Answer (score 1):

You use generics and function overload:

```
func isEqual<T: Equatable>(a: T, b: T) -> Bool {
    return a == b
}

func isEqual<T, U>(a: T, b: U) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

If both variables have the same type, as that type conforms to `Equatable`, then the compiler will choose the first function, otherwise will go the second one.

This will work for Objective-C objects too, providing you cast to `NSObject` before calling the function: `isEqual(var1 as? NSObject, var2 as? NSObject)`

Comment: Even if I knew the types when calling the function (I don't), it seems to pick the wrong `isEqual` anyway. But because I don't know the types when I call, it would always pick the `return false` function.

Comment: In the Playground, `isEqual("test", b: "test")` seems to return false. But the problem is, I'll actually be calling `isEqual` with two types that the compiler sees as unknown anyway, so the compiler has no way to know if it can pick the generic function, so it always picks the default one.

Comment: If you know what types you expect those variables to be, then you can cast them to those types. If you don't know, then you'd need a common class for those objects, `NSObject` would suffice for example.

Comment: @Robert I also updated my second function by making it generic, Swift seems to prefer concrete type over generic one, this is why it picked up the second one.

Comment: For example `isEqual(["test"] as NSArray, ["test"] as NSArray)` gives true

Comment: Thanks, there is a discrete (but large) set of types it can possibly be, so I'll probably just end up writing my own protocol like Adam suggested with an `isEqual` method or something which every type has to implement. I was really hoping that Swift would be able to cast two objects to Equatable in such a way that I could compare them—I think that could be done without violating type safety so maybe in the future I'll be able to change how it works!

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that if `a` and `b` differ in type then they are never equal, you can use a generic function with constraint to achieve the goal.

```
func isEqual<T : Equatable>(a: T, b: T) -> Bool {
    return a == b;
}
```

You cannot have `a` and `b` differ in type, as the `Equatable` protocol assumes that the LHS and RHS of the comparison are of the same type. This seems a reasonable constraint, but one can certainly write a notion of equality that doesn't require this. In these cases, you'll need your own equality protocol.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't be possible because the place calling `isEqual` does not know their types. You can assume the types come out of an array of `Any`, i.e: `[Any]`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to do what I wanted with Swift yet, so I think I probably will just make all my types implement an `isEqual` method via a protocol or something without making them refer to `Self`.